# Средства автоматизации в Linux

Tags: linux, автоматизация

Стоит задача автоматизации процессов в Linux. Кто знает, какие есть средства автоматизации, чтобы могли:
-запускать программы через командную строку с наборами параметров
-параметры запуска могли изменяться в соответствии с условиями
-команды о запуске и условия могли подаваться из бекэнда web-сервера(а также без него)
-возможность выполнения автоматически в назначенное время или период

Из подобных средств знаком только с sh. Есть ли более удобные и мощные инструменты. Как стандарты в данной области? Где почитать? Кто чем пользуется?

Comment: Да, основное средство **bash** (и аналогичные ему sh, csh, ksh, zsh ...) В принципе вы можете использовать любой язык с [repl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) (python, lisp, tcl, perl ...). Большинство из них в конечном итоге для запуска будут использовать sh (точнее, интерпретатор по умолчанию, прописанный в вашем entry в /etc/passwd).  Автоматический вызов по времени -- cron (тоже может исполнять sh script, предоставляемый вами). Для запуска в batch режиме посмотрите [nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

Comment: Спасибо. А как быть с бэкендом сервера. Допустим на одной машине php или С# бэкенд. Каким образом можно вызывать исполнение sh скриптов на этой же машине или на удалённом сервере.

Comment: imho и php и c# умеют запускать shell. Что он должен далее делать зависит от конкретной задачи

Comment: «автоматизации процессов» — слишком обширное понятие... лучше разбираться на основе конкретного примера... и заодно указать, какого уровня нужно решение...

Comment: @Fat-Zer. Конкретно. 1.На сервере есть база данных и инструменты для подготовки данных. Нужно автоматизировать процесс, так, чтобы он самостоятельно запускался в определённый период времени.2. Теже самые инструменты и БД.  Пользователь загружает данные на сервер. Я хочу, чтобы инструменты выполнили определённую типовую работу. Я не прошу расписывать конкретно, хотелось бы узнать какие существуют инструменты помимо sh.

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov, в таком случае, пожалуй, основные моменты уже сказали — обычно пишут свои костыли на произвольном скриптовом языке, периодический запуск — через cron, запуск из стороннего софта — через функции семейства `system()`... Если не нужна сложная логика/отчёты о работе в каком-то конкретном формате, то обычно этого хватает...